# How to use string in function arguments without quotes (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I use a for loop on a list of strings, I need to use that string as an argument in the function but without the quote.

```
for (i in liste_of_string){
    plot_list[[i]] <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x_data, y=i))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    theme(legend.position="none")
}
```

What I actually need is on the `y=i` I need to use the value of `i` which is a string so something like `"Dog"` but i need to remove the quotes. So it will basically be `y="Dog"` but I want to have `y=Dog`.

Note that I already tried `y=noquote(i)` but it gives an error because of the type of what returns the function `noquote()`.

Not sure if it's clear but any help or idea would be top !

Comment: This is a good use case for the `.data` pronoun.  Leave as strings and use `y = .data[[i]]`. I show an example of using this in a function in a blog post [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/#create-a-plotting-function) if it is useful at all.

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what i was looking for ! :)

Answer (score 1):

We could convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
 for (i in liste_of_string){
    plot_list[[i]] <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x_data, y= !! rlang::sym(i)))+
     geom_boxplot()+
    theme(legend.position="none")
  }
```

Comment: Yes it worked well for me thank you ! @aosmith also mentioned the .data[[i]] which works as well.